# Error: 'Flow': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: c#

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

namespace CofBalu { 
class StrongNo { 
static int Factorial(int rem) { 
    if (rem == 1) return 1;
     else return Factorial(rem - 1) * rem; } 

static int StrongNo(int n) { 
     int rem=0,Strong=0; 
     while (n > 0) { 
     Strong = Strong + Factorial(rem = n % 10);
     n = n / 10; 
     } 
return Strong; 
} 

static void Main() { 
   Console.Write("Enter a no: "); 
   int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
   if (StrongNo(n) == n) Console.Write("Yes, "+n+" is a STRONG NO."); 
     else Console.Write("No, " + n + " is not a STRONG NO."); 
   Console.ReadLine(); 
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: You can't define `StrongNo` function in `StrongNo` class. Rename the function and sing you cleary know its c# code why did you tagged it with JavaScript

Comment: put question properly so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

Your method `static int StrongNo(int n)` is having the same name as the class name. And method name which have the name as that of a class are called constructor. And constructors do not have a return type.

So you can try to rename your function like this:

```
static int StrongNumber(int n)
```